# How to know why a pgRouting function returns "FAIL"?

Tags: pgrouting

I am getting a "FAIL" message back when executing `pgr_createTopology` on a particular table, but the reason is not obvious. Is there any way to know precisely why the function is failing? Perhaps some sort of pgRouting log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a message for each failure, but eventually one (or more) have been forgotten?

You could try do debug the problem by modifying the `pgr_createTopology` function, for example by adding more intermediate output [to the pgsql function](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/common/sql/pgrouting_topology.sql).

There is no pgRouting log, except the messages generated with `raise notice`.

Comment: These messages are coming up as notices, now I know what is wrong.